# Crystal Reports Arroja "E_NOINTERFACE" cuando reporte.SetDataSource(ds);

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, dataset

Arroja la **Exception** al crear un Reporte y pasarle un `Dataset`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(tabla);
tabla.TableName = "tablename";

Rpt.MyRpt reporte = new Rpt.MyRpt();
reporte.SetDataSource(ds);
```

La Excepcion sucede al realizar `debug` y No sucede en otras aplicaciones

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2015

**Datos de la Exception:**

**Fuente:** mscorlib

**Mensaje:**

> No se puede convertir el objeto COM del tipo 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' al tipo de interfaz 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. Ocurrió un error de operación debido a que la llamada QueryInterface en el componente COM para la interfaz con IID '{98CDE168-C1BF-4179-BE4C-F2CFA7CB8398}' generó el siguiente error: No such interface supported (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

**Stack Trace:**

> en System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
>      en CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Refresh()
>      en CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.Refresh(RequestContext reqContext)
>      en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Refresh(RequestContext reqContext)
>      en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Refresh()
>      en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type)
>      en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
>      en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet)
>      en [Mi linea de codigo]

Answer (score 1):

Tenia diferentes "SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine" para 32 y 64 bits.

13.0.15 (x86)

13.0.21 (x64).

Aparentemente la version 13.0.21 no tiene retrocompatibilidad, supongo que las demas aplicaciones cargaban la 0.15 por ello no arrojaban la excepcion.

- 1.- Desinstalar completamente la version 13.0.21
- 2.- Eliminar las referencias a crystal reports
- 3.- Agregar manualmente las referencias 13.0.2000 (en mi caso la correcta)

Al realizar estos pasos me arrojo un error diferente:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports 
for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Lo cual es un error mas que documentado y solo tuve que:

4.- Aplicar la siguiente configuracion en mi app.config.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"     />
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema. Si te quieres quedar con la version 13.0.21 debes desinstalar cualquier version previa, instalar las [runtimes de la 13.0.21](https://www.parthpatel.net/install-crystal-report-runtime/#How_to_install_Crystal_Report_Runtime) y reiniciar (si es servidor, con las runtimes es suficiente).

Si instalas Visual Studio 2017, veras que no puedes abrir la .rpt, eso es porque necesitas CR for VS version 13.0.21. Mismo procedimiento, desinstalas toda version previa, [instalas la version 21](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_21.exe), luego reinicias la pc. Deberas cambiar las referencias de tu proyecto a las dll de CR actualizadas.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la version que tengas instalada, si solo tienes la version de 32 bits instalada debes compilar a x86 o si solo tienes la version de 64 bits instalada debes compilar en x64, si tienes ambas versiones instaladas debes compilar en anycpu.

Si compilas en anycpu pero en la pc tienes la version de 32 bits te mandará un error.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para los que no les funcione yo hice lo siguiente:

1.- desinstalar versiones anteriores en mi casa 13.0.2

2.- instalar versiones nueva 13.0.4

3.- reiniciar pc

4.- abrir visual estudio 2019, y quitar la version 13.0.2 en la parte del proyecto/referencias, marcara errores

5.- agregar nueva referencia seria version 13.0.4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6.- compilar y funciona

Answer (score 0):

yo tambien tuve este error se resuelve asi, cuando instalas CR PARA VS 2015,17,19  debes instalar CR runtime, este mismo runtime se debe instalar en las pc que vas usar el sistema, si lo vas a subir a un host en el servidor debes instalar el runtime, yo tenia el problema que en mi laptop si funcionban los reportes pero al publicarlo en el host me daba este error, tuve que instalar el runtime y se soluciono saludos